# Group rows based on same column values in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have two tables:

1. keywords table

```sh
 id |   phrase   | volume | difficulty
----+------------+--------+------------
```

2. urls table:

```sh
 id |                        url                          keyword_id
----+----------------------------------------------------+------------
```

URLs table has a foreign key to keywords table. Each keyword has multiple URLs. Now we want to group keywords that have more than 3 rows from urls table with matching url column value. We are not able to get proper results using `group by` clause. What would be the best way to achieve the result?

Comment: [A minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would increase the chances of a competent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to reformulate the question :

> How to group the keywords which have in common at least 4 urls in
> table urls ?

for instance grouping keyword1 associated to (url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,url6) and keyword2 associated to (url2,url4,url5,url6,url7) because both keywords share the list of url (url2,url4,url5,url6).

To do so, you can try with a `recursive cte` :

```
WITH RECURSIVE list AS
-- group the keyword_id by url
-- remove the urls associated to only one keyword_id
-- assign a rank id to the resulting rows
(
SELECT array[url] AS url_array
     , array_agg(DISTINCT keyword_id) AS keyword_array
     , row_number() OVER () AS rank
  FROM urls
 GROUP BY url
HAVING array_length(keyword_array, 1) > 1
)
, consolidated_list (url_array, keyword_array, rank) AS
-- iterate on the keyword_arrays whose keyword_id have 1, then 2, then 3, then 4 common urls
-- at every iteration, reduce the keyword_array to the elements which have the new added url in common
(
SELECT *
  FROM list
UNION ALL
SELECT cl.url_array || l.url_array
     , c.keyword_array
     , l.rank
  FROM list AS l
 INNER JOIN consolidated_list AS cl
    ON cl.keyword_array && l.keyword_array
   AND NOT cl.url_array @> l.url_array
   AND l.rank > cl.rank  -- to avoid redundant rows with url_arrays with the same set of elements in different orders
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL  -- intersect the arrays of keyword_ids so that to keep only th common keyword_ids
     ( SELECT array_agg(l.kw) AS keyword_array 
         FROM unnest(cl.keyword_array) AS cl(kw)
        INNER JOIN unnest(l.keyword_array) AS l(kw)
           ON l.kw = cl.kw
     ) AS c
 WHERE array_length(cl.url_array, 1) < 4 -- stop the iterations after the 4th loop even if some keyword_ids may have more than 4 urls in common
)
SELECT keyword_array, url_array
  FROM consolidated_list
 WHERE array_length(url_array, 1) = 4 ;  -- only keep the keywords groups with 4 (or more) common urls
```

The result is a list of arrays of keyword_ids which have in common at least the 4 urls of the associated url_array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looked helpful. But I ended up solving the problem by writing the logic in Python that's my strength.